# "The owned entity type requires to be referenced from another entity type via a navigation"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity in my application called Person. There are two types of users, Student and Professor, that inherit from Person.

Every Person has a settings property:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PersonSettings Settings { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
}

public class Professor : Person
{
}
```

My PersonSettings class is just a couple of properties. It isn't an entity to be stored in the database, so I marked it as Owned:

```
[Owned]
public class PersonSettings
{
    public bool NotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
    public int GymPassId { get; set; }
}
```

These are stored in the database as json, which I'm using EF Core conversion values in my Person entity configuration to serialize and deserialize it:

```
builder.Property(p => p.Settings).HasConversion(
    s => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }),
    s => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonSettings>(s, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }));
```

But when I try to run my application and do a database migration, I'm getting an error saying

> The owned entity type 'PersonSettings' requires to be referenced from another entity type via a navigation. Add a navigation to an entity type that points at 'PersonSettings'.

What am I supposed to do here? I couldn't find anything on the error message. Not sure if it has anything to do with Person being an abstract class.

Comment: Can't reproduce with recent EF Core 2.1.1 bits. Can you include the whole relevant fluent configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also can't repro, but you don't need an Owned Type here.

Using Owned Types is an *alternative* to using JSON serialization of a non-scalar property.  When using Owned Types the type is stored along with the Entity that references it.  So as Owned Type EF would create the Person table with separate columns for Settings_NotificationEnabled, and Settings_GymPassId.

So you can simply remove the OwnedAttribute, and ensure that you don't declare it to be an Entity with a property of type `DbSet<PersonSettings>` in your DbContext.

As to which to pick, I would generally use an Owned Type for this scenario, so you could query the database by the individual PersonSettings properties.

Using JSON conversion of a non-scalar property *is* useful for the case where you have a collection, because EF Core does not currently support collections of Owned Types.

Comment: I was accidentally adding it as a DbSet in my context, thanks!

Comment: As of EF Core 2.2 collections of owned types are supported.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and what solved it for me was to follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#mapping-owned-types-with-table-splitting).

Basically what you want to do is add an `OwnsOne` in your entity configuration for `Person`:

```
builder.OwnsOne(p => p.PersonSettings, ps => {
    //if need be add additional settings here for NotificationsEnabled and GymPassId
});
```

That will create a "link" between Person and PersonSettings which the migration generator uses to construct the script.

Answer (score 0):

Same error here, and the issue was that I had a reference in the owned class to an entity:

```
public class OwnedClass // owned, NOT a DbSet
{
       // ... other properties

        public Guid? CalendarId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CalendarId))]
        public Calendar FactoryCalendar { get; set; } // this is a DbSet
{
```